# Minion tasks on Kohana

Tags: php, command-line-interface, kohana

I have an issue with Minions with Kohana. I want to execute minion task on my server, but seems like Kohana is not able to find the class. I tried on local machine, it works.

What I tried to do:

[image: the terminal]

Log file output:

`2016-08-15 12:07:09 --- EMERGENCY: Minion_Exception_InvalidTask [ 0 ]: Task 'Task_Demo' is not a valid minion task ~ MODPATH/minion/classes/Kohana/Minion/Task.php [ 79 ] in /var/www/ideapitch.com/public_html/index.php:111
2016-08-15 12:07:09 --- DEBUG: #0 /var/www/ideapitch.com/public_html/index.php(111): Kohana_Minion_Task::factory(Array)
 #1 /var/www/ideapitch.com/public_html/modules/minion/minion(4): include('/var/www/ideapi...')
 #2 {main} in /var/www/ideapitch.com/public_html/index.php:111`

By examining the file from where the exeption is thrown, I see, that `class_exists()` function throws false.

How to solve this problem? Maybe some sort of routing is gone wrong? I even did an update from 3.3.1 to 3.3.6, and this didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the task file name from `demo.php` to `Demo.php`. First letter should be capitalized.

Some OS's are case sensitive, so it may works on your local machine, but not on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you have to be very careful with class, folder and file names. I renamed everything, every name now is sentence case, and it works like a charm.